# How to make a circular histogram in which both the axes and the range of values are modified in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe `df` which has a column called `Roll` with values of angles that ranges between -180 to 180. As an example:

```
set.seed(123)
Roll<-sample(seq(from = -180, to = 180, by = 10), size = 200, replace = TRUE)
df<- data.frame(Roll)
head(df$Roll)

[1]  120  -40  -50 -160  180  -50
```

I want to create a circular histogram with the next aesthetic:
[image: gplo]

[image]

Does anyone know how to create a plot like this? I don't know how to transform axes to get this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `coord_polar` to transform a histogram into polar coordinates, and adjust the `start` value in radians (here we want 90 degrees in radians to match your drawing).

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = Roll)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-180, -90, 0, 90, 180)) + 
  coord_polar(start = pi/2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! If it is possible, I wanted to ask you two things. First, how do you get `-180/180` in the plot?. The second question is if it is possible to get the same values for the axes than the picture I have attached now in my post... Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can adjust the `breaks` and `labels` argument for `scale_x_continuous` to get to what you posted as the second picture. You can add the argument `clip = "off"` to `coord_polar` which could help on the cutoff, otherwise recommend looking around for similar posts here if that doesn't solve it.